# Hibernate query to fetch records taking much time

Tags: java, sql, spring, oracle, hibernate

I am trying to retrieve a set of records from a table. The query I am using is:

```
select * from EmployeeUpdates eu where eu.updateid>0 and eu.department = 'EEE'
```

The table EmployeeUpdates has around 20 million records. 'updateid' is the primary key and there are no records currently in the table with the department 'EEE'. But the query is taking lots of time, due to which the web-service call is getting timed out.

Currently we have index only on the column 'updateid'. 'department' is a new column added for which we are expecting 'EEE' records.

What changes can I make to retrieve the results faster?

Comment: Create an index with (department,updated). Or partition using department id as Key (If lesser number of departments are there)

Answer (score 0):

First off, your sql isn't valid, looks like you're missing an 'and' between the 2 conditions.

I'm guessing that all the update ID's are positive, and as its the primary key, they're unique, so I suspect eu.updateid>0 matches every row. This means it's not technically a Tablespace scan, but an index based scan, although if that scan then has all 20 million rows after matching the index, you might as well have a table space scan. The only thing you can really do is add an index to the department field. Depending on what this data is, you could have it on a seperate table, with a numeric primary key and then store that as a foreign key on the eu table. This would mean you scanned through all the departments, then got the updated associated to them, rather than searching every single update for a specific department.

Comment: updated my question with the 'and'. Also as of now, there are just two departments. All the records in the table has the department as 'EC' now. In future, we'll be getting 'EEE' records

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look into using a Table-per-subclass mapping (more here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/inheritance.html#inheritance-tablepersubclass-discriminator). You can make the department the discriminator and then you'd have a EEEEmployeUpdates and ECEmployeeUpdates classes. Your query could change then to just query the EEEEmployeeUpdates.